# Having problems trying to back up a Postgres database from AWS RDS

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump, amazon-rds

I am trying to backup a Postgres database from RDS and I am getting this error message.

> pg_dump: [archiver (db)] query failed: SSL error: unexpected message
>
> pg_dump: [archiver (db)] query was: SET search_path = public,
>   pg_catalog

---

RDS: psql (9.4.4, server 9.4.1)

Running pg_dump from server with the following:
openssl 1.0.1e.30.el6.11
pg_dump (PostgreSQL) 9.4.4

Comment: Do you see this every time you start the dump?

Comment: @dezso yes I see this every time I start the dump, but not immedialty

Comment: I don't think the error is related to the ssl, that might be just an error message not explained properly. I suspect the issue is the 'SET search_path = public, pg_catalog' query. If I change the output of the dump file to be sql, this is indeed present in the sql file.